# What would be correct condition for displaying different alerts in Angular?

Tags: angular

I created contact form and i'm handling if request is success or has errors.

In BehaviourSubject i store true or false.

- success = true
- errors = false

Now i would display correct alert after submitting form.

When value has:
0 - alerts should be disabled
true - display success alert
false - display error alert

With what condition i can achieve that? Because currently success is displaying from the begining... and after clickin on X button nothing is changing.

My playground:

```js
isValid$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isValid$.subscribe();
    }

   closeAlert() : void {
    this.isValid$.next(null);
}
```

```html
<!-- ALERT -->
<div *ngIf="isValid$" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
    <!-- Success -->
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()"></button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isValid$" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
    <!-- Error -->
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the ngOnInit and instead make use of the async pipe to subscribe to the observable like so:

```html
<!-- ALERT -->
<div *ngIf="isValid$ | async" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
    <!-- Success -->
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()"></button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isValid$ | async" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
    <!-- Error -->
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()"></button>
</div>
```

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  isValid$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isValid$ = of(true);
  }
}
```

In your case, the isValid$ observable is filled differently of course, but reacting upon it is the same.

You can also check and experiment the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wvx9mt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

BehaviourSubject is a Subject. We need to use it as observable here. and this observable can be subscriber in the template using async pipe.

```
{
   isValid = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

   closeAlert() : void {
      this.isValid.next(null);
   }

   get isValid$() {
      this.isValid.asObservable();
   }
}






     <!-- ALERT -->
<ng-container *ngIf="(isValid$ | async) !== null">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'alert-success': (isValid$ | async) === true, 'alert-danger' : (isValid$ | async) === false }" class="alert alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert">
      {{ (isValid$ | async) ? 'Success' | 'Error' }}
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()"></button>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me at all. It display success message and i'm able to close it but error is not working.

Comment: I have updated the code. It was because ngIf was false when async value is null.
Please check now